# How to add read-after-update consistency to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to use S3 as a datastore for an application (for reasons that are not relevant to this question, I can't use a proper DBMS).
My issue is that I want read-after-update consistency: if I try to read an object immediately after *updating* it, I want to be guaranteed to get the updated object.

S3 guarantees read-after-write consistency (i.e if you try to read an object immediately after creating it, you're guaranteed to succeed).
However, it doesn't guarantee read-after-update consistency (i.e if you try to read an object immediately after *updating* it, you may get a previous version of the object).
Additionally it has some [more caveats](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel).

What can I add to my solution so that it would have read-after-update consistency?

I've thought of a couple of options:

1. **A write-through cache:** each write updates a cache first (thinking of using mongoDB as I'm most familiar with it, and it has fast reads for recent objects), then to S3.  Each read tries the cache first, and falls back to S3 if not found.
   However, this solution doubles the chances of failure (i.e if mongoDB is down, *or* S3 is down, then my whole database is down). Ideally I'd like to have only S3 as a point of failure.
2. **Always write new objects, never update:** I thought I could work around this by utilizing the read-after-write guarantee; instead of creating object `/my-bucket/obj-id.json`, I'll create `/my-bucket/obj-id/v1.json`. When I update I'll just create V2 etc.
   When reading, I'll need to list the keys with the `obj-id` path, and choose the latest version.
   However, one of the above caveats is:

   > A process writes a new object to Amazon S3 and immediately lists keys within its bucket. Until the change is fully propagated, the object might not appear in the list.

Is there any way to "cheat" S3's eventual consistency? Or Am I stuck with a cache component?
Or maybe there's a third, better, idea?
thanks!